# jQuery - getting last div that has a width > 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more efficient way than looping through all my divs and checking there widths to find the last one that has a width > 0?

Here is ab example of what I'm going through, I get this using this call:

```
// My Call
$( ".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider" ).find(".color-region")

// Example result of above call
[<div class="color-region" style="width: 1;"></div>,
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 2;"></div>
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 3;"></div>
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 4;"></div>
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 0;"></div>
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 0;"></div>]
```

Looping I would find the 4th div with width 4. Is there something I can change/add onto my $( ".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider" ).find(".color-region") call to get the last div with width > 0 in 1 line or just without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the elements in the set

```
.filter(function(){ return $(this).width() > 0; })
```

and then [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last element in the set.

The entire code will look like this:

```
$( ".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider" ).find(".color-region").filter(function(){ return $(this).width() > 0; }).last()
```

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is starting backwards. So

```
    var reversed =
          $(".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider").find(".color-region").get().reverse();

    $(reversed).each(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > 0) {
            ....
        }
    });
```

**Update**

If your `HTML` is always like

```
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 0;"></div>
 <div class="color-region" style="width: 0;">
```

you can do

```
$(".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider")
      .find('.color-region:not([style="width: 0;"]):last')
```

This approach uses [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [**:last**](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/). However, I caution you that this approach is less robust than the former.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider" ).find(".color-region").not(function () { return !$(this).width(); }).last();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last`

```
$(".color-region:last").width()
```

This will return the last element which is having the class name `color-region`

**Edit**

```
var lastDiv = $(".color-region").filter(function() {
    return $(this).width > 0
}).last();
```

Comment: which gives the last div.. not the last div with a width > 0